# How can I show an image using Javascript starting with a jpg-encoded string?

Tags: javascript, image, dom, image-processing, jpeg

An annoying API that I have to deal with provides an image as a jpg, but it is a JSON-encoded string within a larger JSON object, rather than just making the jpg available at some url. I have code to access this api with javascript, but then how do I get the image to show up on the page?

update: The API providing the image is accessed from javascript rather than a server, so ideal would be a pure javascript solution. I don't have to support IE6 but I do have to support IE7, Firefox, and Chrome. The jpg isn't base64 encoded but I could base64 encode it in javascript.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? What about IE6/7?

Comment: Is the string data itself base-64 encoded?

Comment: could you just post the json?

Comment: the json format is basically a dictionary with {"jpg": "the-encoded-jpg"} and some other irrelevant keys. so I have the binary jpg data available in javascript, but there isn't going to be any helpful way to use the json directly.

Comment: I didn't think you could put pure binary in JSON - isn't it encoded with _something_ ?

Comment: Well it is an option to get it base64 encoded, so anything that works with base64 works.

Comment: see my answer, then.  Use Javascript DOM methods to add a new IMG tag containing the base 64 data in the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the JSON string is base 64 encoded then you can output it as a [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), e.g.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,...." />
```

This also works (without the base64 tag) if the string is URL encoded (e.g. mostly ASCII, and `%xx` format for non-printing and non-HTML-safe characters).

Comment: This is the best solution I've been able to find. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work in IE 7, so I think I will have to use Flash. Thanks though, I did not know about Data URIs.